# Hartog's theorem and affineness?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is the following true? I see it is true for X affine, but I do mot know how to show it otherwise.
Let X be a normal noetherian local scheme of dimension 2, with closed point s. Show that $X \setminus \{s\}$ is not affine.

Comment: What is a local scheme?

Comment: In EGA I a local scheme is a scheme of the form Spec(R) for a local ring R. But this is not meant here ...

Comment: As $X$ is noetherian, having exactly one closed point is equivalent to be Spec(a local ring).

Answer (score 1):

(I am unsure what you mean by "local scheme", so I'll interpret it to mean that $X$ is dimension 2 locally at $s$.)

It is false if your scheme is not necessarily separated: Consider, for example, the plane with doubled origin. On the other hand, if your scheme is separated, assume $X\setminus\{s\}$ is affine. Consider an affine open neighborhood $U$ of $s$; Because the intersection of two affine sets is affine in a separated scheme, $U \setminus \{s\}$ is affine, and $U$ is affine, so we have reduced to the affine case.

For the affine case: By Hartog's theorem, the map induced by the inclusion induces an isomorphism of global sections, and as they are affine, the inclusion must be an isomorphism, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: Local scheme I mean a scheme with just 1 closed point. Thanks!